# Storing multiple parameter values in another parameter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to develop a report in SQL Server Reporting Services using parameters.

I have created a searchable parameter (as described in the link below) which is working as it should. I want to expand the functionality so that I can make multiple searches before viewing my report.

My problem is that when I have searched and selected a value and seach for another value the selected is reset (this is because the parameter where I select is cascading to the one where I search). Is there any way I can 'save' my selected parameter so that I, in the end, have all the seached and selected values which I then can filter on?

Searchable parameter: http://romiller.com/2008/07/29/searchable-dependant-parameters-in-ssrs/

(My problem is the same as Peter Schmidts comment in the link above.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to get the results you desire is to create separate dataset with a required parameter that depends on a search term from the other parameters...this is very hackish and requires a search on multiple values stored procedure. This would cause the report to postback after you select your search criteria then display another parameter dropdown after a second refresh where the user could select the desired id based on search terms and then finally clicking the "view report" button a second time.